# How to display all image formats in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, png, jpeg

I want to display a lot of types of images in flutter app (like format SVG, png, and jpg)
But I have a problem showing SVG images in my flutter app.
I'd used [flutter-svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package to display SVG images, but it doesn't support png and jpg images. :(

How to resolve it?

Comment: Are you asking about embedded png and jpg inside svg, or regular png and jpg files?

Comment: I mean regular png and jpg files

Answer (score 0):

Flutter SVG package is only for SVG images. For png and jpg you need to implement normal image display method.

Comment: Unfortunately, my images may be of any format (like format svg, png and jpg) :((

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this code for accept all format:**

```
 (imageF.contains('svg') ? SvgPicture.network(image) : Image.network(image)),
```